# Why are graphs represented using an adjacency list instead of an adjacency set?

Tags: graph, adjacency-list

If each node maps to a set of the nodes it has edges to, instead of a list, we would gain the ability to gain constant time lookup of edges, instead of having to traverse the whole list. The only disadvantage I can think of is slightly more memory overhead and time to enumerate the edges of a node, but not asymptotically significantly so.

Comment: It's not "constant time", it's "log(nb elements in the set)" time ! (to answser the question, if you use std::set<>, then memory overhead is significant, as compared to Compressed Row Storage for instance)

Comment: @BrunoLevy A `HashSet` will give you constant lookup of vertices.

Comment: @Carcigenicate yes, I agree that it can give constant lookup, but it is not under general circumstances and requires some care. I think that obtaining guaranteed constant-time behavior for any sparsity pattern is very difficult (if not impossible).

Answer (score 0):

I think "list" is just a generic label, not to be taken literally. I've used a `Set` and it works perfectly well.

If I recall correctly, my textbook also used a `Set`.